# Actualizar datos en lineas especificas de un campo base de datos

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Estoy pasando una base de datos de Joomla a Wordpress, y algunas URL que requiero cambiar no las puedo utilizar porque son rutas que no van a existir en el sitio web con Wordpress.

Los datos los recibo asi:

```
<p>lo nuevo del cantante puertorriqueño Chayanne y es que el pasado 7  de febrero 
presentó <strong>''A Solas Con Chayanne''</strong> un DVD/CD que  contiene una de las 
mayores presentaciones que ofreció en el Auditorio  Nacional de la Ciudad de México 
durante su éxitosa gira ''No Hay  Imposibles'', cabe destacar que este álbum también 
viene en formato  Blu-ray. ¡Para que pedir más!</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-family: trebuchet ms,geneva;"><br /> 
</span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img 
src="http://midominio.com/images/stories/life/home/Chayanne025.JPG" 
border="0" width="333" height="500" style="vertical-align: middle;" /></p>
```

Y me estoy enfrentando al problema de que requiero actualizar las URL de las etiquetas **SRC**

```
src="http://midominio.com/images/stories/life/home/Chayanne025.JPG"
```

Cambiar lo que este en esa URL por otro nombre que debo generar. Esto para que las imagenes
se puedan ver en mis entradas.

Con la funcion DOMDocument de PHP logro obtener las URL, pero no se como actualizar las URL en la base de datos, o cuando vaya a guardar la entrada en la nueva base de datos, la URL se actualice a una que yo defina.

Espero me logren entender, estoy bloqueado aqui, me falta el conocimiento para lograr la solucion que requiero.

Si consideran una mejor solucion quedo atento

Saludos

Comment: ¿Y cual seria la ruta destino de esos enlaces de imágenes?  ¿Has probado con un simple [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)?

Comment: Seria actualizar el campo donde estan esos enlaces insertados, actualizar el enlace a la ruta correcta para que se vea la imagen. Porque es texto que se muestra en una entrada de post

Comment: prueba con `$campo_modificado = str_replace('src="http://midominio.com/images/stories/life/home/', 'src="http://midominio.com/nuevaruta/images/', $campo_actual);` y luego le metes el $campo_modificado al campo de la tabla en lugar de lo que tenia

Comment: Entiendo, pero se guardaría en el campo con todo el texto que esta entre los enlaces?

Comment: A ver, cuando haces un str_replace **solo reemplaza lo que está en el primer parámetro**, dejando sin tocar lo que no sea eso.  Aún así, andate con cuidado porque si te equivocas en la cadena a sustituir, puedes liarla.  Yo de ti haria la prueba en una tabla copiada primero, luego haria un backup de la primera tabla y luego las sustituiria. Si después detectas problemas imprevistos siempre puedes volver atras con la de backup.