# Como Generar URL personalizadas en imagenes para WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-imagenes, wordpress-api

Tengo muchas entradas con imagenes insertadas que esta subidas en unas URL que no estan en mi Wordpress Actual, las rutas varian.

por ejemplo.

```
midominio.com/images/stories/imagen.png
midominio.com/froto/hola/imagen.png
```

¿Puedo hacer que Wordpress vea esas rutas?

Estuve buscando un poco en google, pero no logro formular la pregunta correcta.

Mi ruta de imagenes actual

```
C:\laragon\www\remere\wp- 
content\uploads\roomere\images\stories\life\home
```

Algunas rutas que probe

```
C:\laragon\www\remere\roomere\images\stories\life\home
```

Cuando llamo a mi url local:

http://midominio.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/dxc__mz3371619.png

Me da error 404

Saludos

Comment: Si ahora quieres eso ([antes preguntabas otra cosa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/541976/actualizar-datos-en-lineas-especificas-de-un-campo-base-de-datos)) tan solo debes subirlas a la misma estructura de carpetas que tenias antes creándola si es necesario. Por ejemplo, en la raiz de tu dominio crea la carpeta **images**, dentro de images **stories** y alli copias todas las imágenes que venian del joomla de esa carpeta, y así con todo.

Comment: busco 2 soluciones, las 2 son aceptables. Si, asi lo hice, sin embargo retorna 404 para las rutas creadas

Comment: Pues entonces es que no estas poniendo bien las rutas, no hay otra.  Pon un esquema de tus carpetas actuales desde la raíz del dominio y donde tienes las imagenes en la pregunta

Comment: Informacion agregada

Comment: Prueba con `http://midominio.com/wp-content/uploads/roomere/images/stories/life/home/Chayanne025.JPG` (lo he sacado de la otra pregunta)

Comment: mismo error 404

Comment: Como lo tienes en tu pc, si con un gestor gráfico de archivos te vas a la carpeta donde está la imagen que sea que quieres ver en tu dominio, y la arrastras a un navegador, ¿cual es su ruta completa que aparece en la url?

Comment: Para esa imagen en especifico seria esta `file:///C:/laragon/www/rumberos/wp-content/uploads/rumberos/images/stories/life/home/dxc__mz3371619.jpg`

Comment: Listo, no entiendo que tenia de malo en las rutas, copie y pegue la que me dio la imagen y ahora si la muestra

Comment: Yo creo que así te la tendria que mostrar: `http://midominio.com/wp-content/uploads/rumberos/images/stories/life/home/dxc__mz3371619.jpg`  (antes ponias **roomere** no se porque)

Comment: Si,, asi la muestra, claro ahora tengo la duda, es que, las url de las imagenes son otras y en Wordpres por la jerarquia mis imagenes deben tener estas carpetas en sus rutas    /wp-content/uploads , claro aqui puedo editar los enlaces con la funcion que me indicaste en el otro post, pero sigue siendo un problema para los post con muchas imagenes. Pensare un rato en como hacerlo sin utilizar tanto codigo. Al final todo es para poder pasar la informacion a wordpress

Comment: Pues entonces aplica lo que te he comentado en la otra pregunta, lo del str_replace... mmm... ¿porque dices que no puedes aplicar esa función?  Debes crearte un script que recorra en las tablas de la base de datos, todos los campos que contengan esas rutas y con esa función cambiarlas.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el nombre de la imagen antes de subirla a wordpress. Como te gustaría que quede en tu URL.
Las que ya tienes arriba las puedes editar.
Tienes que ir al menu Medios / Biblioteca / Elige la imagen que prefieras / ve a Editar más detalles / Y donde esta el Permalink: puedes editar el URL.

Si quieres cambiar la estructura de tu URL, ve al Menu Ajustes / Cambia a nombre de entrada u estructura personalizada, según te convenga.